# org-gcal complain about client id/secret

Tags: init-file, error, org-gcal

I setup `org-gcal-client-id` and secret.  I do `org-gcal-reload-client-id` (`-secret` too) but at each Emacs startup I receive a warning that these 2 variable must be set.

Comment: Check you have the most up to date `org-gcal`: there was a recently fixed bug around this issue.

Comment: The package I used  (org-gcal-20221212.1817) has no command org-gcal-request token. So I looked back to an old backup I made and replaced with org-gcal-2022-08-09.1955) which has well this command org-gcal-request-token.  I dont really know what happened but now is working fine and no more warning at startup.

Comment: This may lead to trouble down the road: you are using (I think) a version before the new oauth2 mechanism was introduced.  This means that Google may start rejecting the authentication method your version uses (they have promised to do so but have not done it yet).